# Number of free parameters in a Standard Model with Neutrino oscillation

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

In [two](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196073/how-many-of-the-standard-model-free-parameters-are-mutually-independent-all-of) [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172846/free-parameters-in-the-standard-model) questions, it was asked how many free parameters the standard model has. Without neutrino oscillation, there are [19 free parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#Construction_of_the_Standard_Model_Lagrangian). Now it turned out that neutrinos have a mass aswell, thus the Standard Model should/has been extended.

My question: How many parameters are required to take into account the oscillation? Does it work with only 3 mass-parameters for the 3 different known neutrinos, or are there additional parameters necessary (if so, what are they standing for)? Or is it possible to describe the effects with only 1 or 2 parameters (if so, what idea reduces the effect of the three masses to less free parameters)?

Comment: The answer didn't state it in so many words, although it is implied, but massive oscillating neutrinos add 7 parameters - three masses and four PMNS parameters. If neutrinos actually have Majorana rather than Dirac masses, you need a total of 9 additional parameters, since an analog to the PMNS matrix with Majorana neutrinos requires more parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mass and weak eigenstates are related by the [Pontecorvo-Maki–Nakagawa–Sakata matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo%E2%80%93Maki%E2%80%93Nakagawa%E2%80%93Sakata_matrix), which is a $3\times 3$ unitary matrix. Therefore, it can be parametrized by four parameters. The usual choice is the three mixing angles $\theta_{12}$, $\theta_{13}$ and $\theta_{23}$, and a CP-violating phase $\delta_{CP}$ (or, if neutrinos are Majorana fermions, 3 different CP-violating phases). Oscillation experiments provide information about the mixing angles, but not the phase.

Note that oscillation observation is not sensitive to neutrino masses, only to *the square of the difference of neutrino masses*. Therefore, it could be possible that only two of the three neutrino flavours have non-zero mass.

The consequences of the existence of the CP-violating phase are

- In a difference between the oscillation $\nu_\alpha\to \nu_\beta$ and $\bar{\nu}_\alpha \to \bar{\nu}_\beta$ (and also $\nu_\beta\to \nu_\alpha$, if CPT symmetry is conserved).
- A non-zero contribution to the electric dipole of charged leptons. Nevertheless, this effect is "neglibly small and unaccesible to experiments".
- If neutrinos are Majorana fermions, the spectrum of the neutrinoless double beta decay *might* be sensitive to Majorana CP-violating phases.

**References:**

- K. Nakamura and S. T. Petcov: *Neutrino mass, mixing and oscillations*. Particle Data Group ([Link to pdf](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf))
- G. C. Branco, R. Gonzalez Felipe and F. R. Joaquim: *Leptonic CP violation*. Rev.Mod.Phys. **84** (2012) 515-565. ([arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5332))

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting. I didn't know about the CP-violating phase. How do you measure that value, if you cannot see it in neutrino-oscillations, but it is not in the standard-model? That would mean, there is another beyond-SM effect related to neutrinos, or am I getting something wrong?